# Escape space with backslash in java

Tags: java, string, replace, escaping, replaceall

I want to replace spaces from path string. I tried below but doesn't seems to be working :

```
String path = "/Users/TD/San Diego";
path=path.replaceAll(" ","\\ ");
System.out.println(path);
```

Goal is to convert

> "/Users/TD/San Diego" to "/Users/TD/San\ Diego"

Any further space from string also needs to be replaced with "\ "

Comment: Why? They work as-is.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You could change

```
path = path.replaceAll(" ", "\\ ");
```

to escape the backslash

```
path = path.replaceAll(" ", "\\\\ ");
```

When I do that, I get (the requested)

```
/Users/TD/San\ Diego
```

Another option would be using `String.replace` like

```
path = path.replace(" ", "\\ ")
```

which outputs the same.

Answer (score 0):

The suggested solution did not work for me (in Android Java).

So this is what I've came up with, after quite a few attempts:

```
path = path.replace(" ", (char) 92 + " ");
```